# Do license notes on user profiles have any effect?

Tags: discussion, licensing

I have noted that some users have placed notices in their profile that they say license their contributions to SO or SE.

Now I know very little about licensing TBH, can barely tell an MIT from a BSD, but I would have thought that by using the site users are agreeing to the T&C's and thus the license that SE places and that notes on a profile would have zero effect on that.

Do user profile notes override the license placed by the use of the site or are such users kidding themselves?

Comment: Are you sure they are asserting a license *to SE*, or are they asserting an (additional) license to their content *posted to SE*?

Comment: Maybe they should be suspended for not accepting term #2 in the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

Comment: @AlonEitan: they have accepted by posting, that is non-revokable. We won't suspend anyone for misunderstanding and posting a separate license. If they tried to *remove the content from the site* then we may have to suspend an account to limit the damage and ease clean-up.

Comment: An example I came across this morning: "Any code of mine that I publish anywhere on stackexchange.com I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the CC0. This also applies to documentation/instructions etc." I'm not sure if that counts as an additional or not

Comment: @Toby: that is additional. Moreover, that is a *more permissive license*, giving everyone *more* rights than the CC by-sa 3.0 license already placed on the content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most user profiles that assert a license that I have seen, assert an **additional** license (like [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975049/patszim?tab=profile)). As the author of their posts, they have that right, they can give you additional rights on their works. You can license your own content under as many licenses as you like.

However, if someone is posting a license for *Stack Overflow* (or any other Stack Exchange site) to use their posted content, then by posting they already agreed to the [CC by-sa 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) linked in the footer of every page. Posting a different license in their profile makes no difference here.

So in summary: posting a license in your profile is fine, but it only applies *in addition* to the content license already in place. Pick whatever license you want to apply to you when you want to re-use their posts, then comply by that license.

Comment: But is there any problem that having a more permissive license cancels the attribution to SO required by the CC BY-SA 3.0 licence?

Comment: @AlonEitan: why is that a problem? The author is waiving that requirement *for their own content*. They wrote that content, they want you to use it more freely. They are *giving you the right to not have to attribute the work*.

Comment: I suppose the real question here is if I put something in my profile granting a far more permissive licence to my content (no attribution required for instance) - ie: I'm waivering my rights of the licence but not revoking any....

Comment: @JonClements: you have that right, but I have the right to then ignore that license and stick with the CC by-sa 3.0 license already in place.

Comment: @AlonEitan: or to put it differently: the content you post on SO is not *exclusively licensed*. You are only agreeing to grant a specific license to reuse *your* work. There is no ownership transfer, the content is still yours to use elsewhere as you please. That gives you the right to do other things with your content, including granting more licenses.

Comment: Or to rephrase it: it's only useful to give people *more* permissions to do stuff with your works (such as sharing without attribution). Restricting it beyond CC by-sa is useless.